# Where to include the configuration for Phaxio gem in rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am interested in using Phaxio's API using the [Ruby gem created by Gristmill](https://github.com/gristmill/phaxio). According to the Github repo for the Ruby Gem I will need to include the following in my Rails project. My question is where would be the recommended place to include them in?

```
require 'phaxio'

Phaxio.config do |config|
  config.api_key = "your_key"
  config.api_secret = "your_secret"
end
```

Might be worth mentioning that I am not going to include my key and secret in the same location. I am thinking it would be more appropriate to put it in a .env file and use Dotenv. With that said What I will be doing would look more like the following:

```
require 'phaxio'

Phaxio.config do |config|
  config.api_key = ENV['PHAXIO_API_KEY']
  config.api_secret = ENV['PHAXIO_SECRET_KEY']
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put it in `/config/initializers/phaxio_configuration.rb`.

Comment: @mustaccio This is the very definition of an answer. It might have room for improvement, but that doesn't mean we need to delete it.