# How to configure a GEM in a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Sorry, I'm back with another noob/dumb question. However, I have been working on this for a while now and can't seem to find a definitive answer/solution.
I found this answer from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239057/where-to-include-the-configuration-for-phaxio-gem-in-rails-project?answertab=active#tab-top)but it's really specific to the gem in question... I also found another answer or 2 but it really wasn't clear enough.

So I'm trying to use this gem for my app: https://github.com/shideneyu/kraken_client#configuration and there's a whole section about configuration that I would like to use:

```
KrakenClient.configure do |config|
      config.api_key     = ENV['KRAKEN_API_KEY']
      config.api_secret  = ENV['KRAKEN_API_SECRET']
      config.base_uri    = 'https://api.kraken.com'
      config.api_version = 0
      config.limiter     = true
      config.tier        = 2
end
```

Note that they do not precise any 'require' in this code so I'm guessing that I won't be needing it (unlike the 'phaxio' gem from the answer I found on SO)?

I've tried to create a kraken_client.rb file in /config/initializers/ but when prompting the rails console it won't use it.

My objective is to first test the gem through the console to be able to build the rails app on that afterwards.

I could use the other option cited in the gem repo:

```
KrakenClient.load({base_uri: 'https://api.kraken.com', tier: 3}).config.tier
```

But I'm really not sure how to use that either (sorry... I'm really, really new). So my question is how can I configure this gem and generally how are gems configured once installed in a rails project?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `config/initializers/load_lib.rb`(create if does not exist) write: `require 'kraken_client'` and save
after it come to `rails c` and call it

Comment: Hey Alexey! Thanks for your help but I'm afraid it's not working. I might be missing something somewhere. Here are the steps I took: Created the `config/initializers/load_lib.rb` since there was none and I just put `require 'kraken_client'` in there, saved, closed and launched rails console it still says that  I need to pass some config in... :S 
again, sorry I have no clue on how it actually works, I usually (until now) installed the gems and they would sort of... work on their own.

Comment: ok, did you accordingly https://github.com/shideneyu/kraken_client#configuration steps: 1) Add this line to your application's Gemfile:
`gem 'kraken_client', '~> 1.1.5'`
And then execute:
`$ bundle`  ?

Comment: Yes this I did...if I run it again I get the line: `Using kraken_client 1.1.5`. Plus I use the "public" part of the gem to retrieve info but that's it... I apparently can't get to use my api-keys to retrieve personal info.

Comment: I seem to be having an issue, even in the console. Here's the code I tried to pass: `2.4.0 :005 > client.public.ticker('XETHZEUR')
 => #<Hashie::Mash XETHZEUR=#<Hashie::Mash a=#<Hashie::Array ["296.00000", "4", "4.000"]> b=#<Hashie::Array ["295.52000", "17", "17.000"]> c=#<Hashie::Array ["296.00000", "1.63170000"]> h=#<Hashie::Array ["298.00000", "298.00000"]> l=#<Hashie::Array ["282.98200", "277.51000"]> o="285.44069" p=#<Hashie::Array ["293.35853", "289.49485"]> t=#<Hashie::Array [6223, 21816]> v=#<Hashie::Array ["34618.09497627", "111824.87773031"]>>> ` but as you can see it yields to nil

Comment: is problem actual still today?

Comment: Hey Alexey! Yes but I found out (thanks to the gem's creator) that the problem might be rooted within the fact that it uses `ENV` variables and that I haven't included them in my project. Which means ultimately that I'm setting the 2 api_key variables to `nil`. If you have material or other ideas though, I'm more than opened to it.

Comment: If you are very stuck in your problem you can try to find communities of gem. Also you can try to open issue in repo, but sometimes maintainers is not very glad help in issue, because issue in general is for bugs, proposals, etc. I do not know rules of it command.

Comment: Hey Alexey! Thanks for your advices! I'm working on it and as soon as I'll get the definitive answer I'll post it here! Thanks again for your help!